# What is the true definition of the word Kadosh in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, language

This question may be simple but I was curious if we have a true definition for it.

People talk about living in a (Kadosh) or holy way. The word gets used a lot but I don't necessarily think I've heard anybody really describe the underlying meaning or definition behind it.

I was curious if we have a true and clear definition for what makes something Kadosh (holy)

Comment: We can't possibly know, we can only find the meaning through its uses in the Mikrah and various interpretations. G-d is called קדוש, but זונה is also called קדשה which opens a lot of options for speculation.

Comment: The other answer implies that there's one meaning to this word which can be wrong, no necessity to have "one meaning fit all". One word can have a different meaning, esp. if it came from different meanings, see https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he